# PHP :How Can i downgrade an gd library in php

Tags: php, gdlib

Is is it possible to downgrade gd-library, If so please tellme how.google did not help me.

Comment: Do you have root access on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. uninstall the current library completely
2. download the source files for the gd version you want
3. Extract the archive
4. ./configure && make && make install (search google on how to install GD from source).
5. Make any config edits required (i.e. add the library to php.ini).

GD Sources can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/downloads